# Is the Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 Logging Application Block thread safe?

Tags: logging, thread-safety, enterprise-library

I have some code that will be logging using the Logging Application Block in Enterprise Library 5.0 from different threads. Is the LAB thread safe? Can I log like normal from different threads or will I need to synchronize the logging code so that is only used from one thread at a time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enterprise Library 5.0 logging is thread safe.

Before logging, EL checks the `IsThreadSafe` property of the `TraceListener`.  If the specific TraceListener is not thread safe then it will perform a `Monitor.Enter(listener);` before calling the listener's `TraceData` method.

Comment: i'm wondering if I should have been able to figure this out or if going to the source is what's required to find out

Comment: @Gabriel, I don't see any discussion of logging thread safety in the official docs only discussion about the Caching Block.  I did see a third party site saying it is thread safe but better to verify.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,Enterprise Library 3.1 Logging is not thread safe.
There is not lock around GetAvailableTraceListeners(IList traceListeners) call in LogWriter
class, which used static in Logger class.